# Error with S3 and Paperclip - Rails 5 - invalid configuration option `:use_accelerate_endpoint'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rubygems, storage, paperclip

I just set up an S3 bucket to upload my images and resources to and whenever I try to create a new book this error pops up. This is my first time using S3 so I am pretty confused. (I have my env all set up too - just didn't share for obvious reasons).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information.

application.rb - code:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
  }
}
```

Error Message
[image]

Comment: Not a good practice to post images, the best is use direct code instead of images

Comment: @fool-dev Hey thanks for letting me know. I just turned those code images into code blocks. I appreciate it!

Comment: Look at that link, I think will help you https://gist.github.com/belgoros/b289a0b57b52d16b99d436ca9b80417f

Comment: @fool-dev Thanks so much this was very helpful. The issue I ran into was actually that I had aws-sdk 2.0 in my gem file and I should of had aws-sdk 2.6. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had `'aws-sdk', '~> 2.0.0'` in my gemfile instead of `'aws-sdk', '~> 2.6'`.